# With Google AppScripts, Exporting data from firebase to google sheet's data have data type with the value

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Google App Scripts and Firestore GoogleAppScripts for data fetching from firestore to google sheet as explained on this library.

Here's my code.

```js
function getGemExchange() {
  // 1. Get a Firestore instance
  const firestore = getFirestore()

  // 2. Get a collection from Firestore
  const userDocuments = firestore.getDocuments('gemExchangeRequests').map(document => document.fields)

  // 3. Get the first document from the collection 
  const first = userDocuments[0];
  const columns = Object.keys(first);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(columns);

  // 4. Turn each document into an array to be appended to the sheet
  userDocuments.forEach(document => {
    const row = columns.map(column => document[column])
    sheet.appendRow(row)
  })
}
```

It all works fine except the values have its data type with it.

```
status  taxAmount   bankDetails gemAmount   uniqueId    serviceFee
{stringValue=PENDING}   {doubleValue=0.02}  {stringValue=U2FsdGVkX1/a2sX4CaKi0Ham/dSSEzlg7QNca236+clZbRDwHZwe8C7Xhy53ybk0c6l34CLYtQ+0KFnDOuAAfUc4WUKRfQTPWxS8NDHP2kREeRzX2BJGZ6JpL3NfxmsbR/dGpvKqy/Pa+Of3guJmjg==}  {integerValue=33}   {stringValue=APR-TC0}   {integerValue=2}
```

So I want to get rid of data types such as "stringValue", "integerValue" or "doubleValue" on my Google Spreadsheet.

For example, I want "PENDING" for the "status" column, not "{stringValue=PENDING}"

What should I do in this case?

Comment: This is the library I used. https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript

Comment: By guessing your values from your question, I posted a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample values of `console.log(JSON.stringify(userDocuments))`? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the reply. There seems to be error with the following code you've asked me to modify. What I need is to have values that are written on google spreadsheet to be like "PENDING" instead of "{stringValue=PENDING}". I also added explanation here. https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/issues/123.  

I cannot figure out how to change those into rawValue TT.. If you can take a look at it, it'd be awesome!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of `error` from `There seems to be error with the following code you've asked me to modify.`. So, an you provide the sample values of `console.log(JSON.stringify(userDocuments))`? By this, I would like to modify the script. When you can do this, please put `console.log(JSON.stringify(userDocuments))` just before the line of `const first = userDocuments[0];`, and can you provide the value in the log?

Comment: Thanks! 

{ gemAmount: { integerValue: '33' },
    bankDetails: { stringValue: 'U2FsdGVkX1/a2sX4CaKi0Ham/dSSEzlg7QNca236+clZbRDwHZwe8C7Xhy53ybk0c6l34CLYtQ+0KFnDOuAAfUc4WUKRfQTPWxS8NDHP2kREeRzX2BJGZ6JpL3NfxmsbR/dGpvKqy/Pa+Of3guJmjg==' },
    serviceFee: { integerValue: '2' },
    date: { timestampValue: '2021-04-06T19:54:21.997Z' },
    subtotal: { integerValue: '55' },
    userId: { stringValue: '0AG3U6cRgcWtyJhRy3f73g2JkQM2' },
    uniqueId: { stringValue: 'APR-TC0' },
    taxAmount: { doubleValue: 0.02 },
    userDetails: { mapValue: [Object] }}

Comment: I though in this case Object.values() should have worked... I'll try again. If you have any other suggestions, plz let me know too!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I think that in your sample value, you might put `console.log(userDocuments)` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(userDocuments))`. If my understanding is correct, can you put `console.log(JSON.stringify(userDocuments))` and provide the value in the log?

Comment: Haha no worries! I did figure out how to work on this thing. So I'll just take your answer. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. When your issue was resolved, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
userDocuments.forEach(document => {
  const row = columns.map(column => document[column])
  sheet.appendRow(row)
})
```

#### To:

```
const values = userDocuments.map(document => columns.flatMap(column => Object.values(document[column])));
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- In this modification, each value is retrieved from `document[column]`. And, the values are put using `setValues` instead of `appendRow`. By this, the process cost will be reduces a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

#### Note:

- I thought that in your script, the arrange of the header row might be changed every run. So, when you want to constant the header row, I would like to propose to declare the header row as a variable in the script.

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)